# Simply Polyline and markers in the one file

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, polyline

I am trying to create a static html page that displays a Polyline of a walking track as well as markers of towns along the way. I have been using the html example files supplied by Google Maps API site. I have two arrays (one for Polyline and one for markers). I can create a sample file to show Polyline and a sample file to show markers.

---------- Here is the Polyline sample --------

```
<script>
  "use strict";
  function initMap() {
    const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
      zoom: 10,
      center: {
        lat: 43.3473702427,
        lng: -1.7866905872
      },
      mapTypeId: "terrain"
    });
    const flightPlanCoordinates = [

{
         lat: 43.3473702427,
         lng: -1.7866905872
 },
{
         lat: 43.3473476954,
         lng: -1.7865623441
 },
{
         lat: 43.3473729249,
         lng: -1.7862672172
 },
{
         lat: 43.3474351186,
         lng: -1.7861244734
 },
{
         lat: 43.3474754356,
         lng: -1.7859851662
 },
{
         lat: 43.347496558,
         lng: -1.7858726811
 },
{
         lat: 43.3475023415,
         lng: -1.7857427616
 },
{
         lat: 43.3474533912,
         lng: -1.7856312823
 },
{
         lat: 43.3467171248,
         lng: -1.7854733672
 },
{
         lat: 43.3458278049,
         lng: -1.7851600517
 },
{
         lat: 43.3450604416,
         lng: -1.7848521005
 },
{
         lat: 43.3443607204,
         lng: -1.7850081716
 },
{
         lat: 43.3441632427,
         lng: -1.7851468921
 },


{
         lat: 43.3423870336,
         lng: -1.7862907704
 },
{
         lat: 43.3423038851,
         lng: -1.7863221187
 },
{
         lat: 43.3422126062,
         lng: -1.7863554787
 },
{
         lat: 43.3421186451,
         lng: -1.7864152417
 },
{
         lat: 43.3419943415,
         lng: -1.786458157
 },
{
         lat: 43.341907924,
         lng: -1.7864865717
 },
{
         lat: 43.3418141305,
         lng: -1.7864960432
 },

{
         lat: 43.3395636734,
         lng: -1.7880662251
 },
{
         lat: 43.3394773398,
         lng: -1.7880819831
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393750805,
         lng: -1.7881052848
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393117134,
         lng: -1.7881597672
 },
{
         lat: 43.3392953686,
         lng: -1.7882843222
 },
{
         lat: 43.3392989729,
         lng: -1.78845305
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393396251,
         lng: -1.788651282
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393413853,
         lng: -1.7887586541
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393360209,
         lng: -1.7888663616
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393474203,
         lng: -1.7890360951
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393621724,
         lng: -1.7891617399
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393969573,
         lng: -1.7892939225
 },
{
         lat: 43.3394075185,
         lng: -1.7894147895
 },
{
         lat: 43.3393995557,
         lng: -1.7894981895
 },
{
         lat: 43.3400335629,
         lng: -1.7926760204
 },
{
         lat: 43.3403750416,
         lng: -1.7943606991
 },
{
         lat: 43.3404274285,
         lng: -1.794564547
 },
{
         lat: 43.3405581024,
         lng: -1.7947906069
 },
{
         lat: 43.3408577554,
         lng: -1.7962014489
 },
{
         lat: 43.3409312647,
         lng: -1.7964569293
 },
{
         lat: 43.3410289977,
         lng: -1.7968221288
 },
{
         lat: 43.341086749,
         lng: -1.797145335
 },
{
         lat: 43.3411341906,
         lng: -1.7975875642
 },
{
         lat: 43.341227565,
         lng: -1.7978497501
 },
{
         lat: 43.3414114639,
         lng: -1.7980664223
 },
{
         lat: 43.3415769227,
         lng: -1.7981714476
 },
{
         lat: 43.3416830376,
         lng: -1.7983020376
 },
{
         lat: 43.3418867178,
         lng: -1.7984791473
 },
{
         lat: 43.3423764724,
         lng: -1.7990746815
 },
{
         lat: 43.3427510597,
         lng: -1.7992604245
 },
{
         lat: 43.3428710885,
         lng: -1.7993480153
 },
{
         lat: 43.3431115653,
         lng: -1.7995948624
 },
{
         lat: 43.3436958678,
         lng: -1.8000118621
 },
{
         lat: 43.34389125,
         lng: -1.800135579
 },
{
         lat: 43.3441171423,
         lng: -1.8003076594
 },
{
         lat: 43.3442825172,
         lng: -1.8004375789
 },
{
         lat: 43.3444631472,
         lng: -1.8005764671
 },
{
         lat: 43.3446667437,
         lng: -1.8007254135
 },
{
         lat: 43.3448162768,
         lng: -1.8008333724
 },
{
         lat: 43.3448740281,
         lng: -1.8008811492
 },

    ];
    const flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: flightPlanCoordinates,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: "#FF0000",
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: 2
    });
    flightPath.setMap(map);
  }
</script>
```

//------- end Polyline sample -----

//------- Start Markers sample -----

```
<script>
let map;

      "use strict";
      function initMap() {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 10,
          center: {
            lat: 43.3062762022,
            lng: -2.7221442573
          },
          mapTypeId: "terrain"
        });
        const iconBase =
          "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/";
        const icons = {
          parking: {
            icon: iconBase + "parking_lot_maps.png",
          },
          library: {
            icon: iconBase + "library_maps.png",
          },
          info: {
            icon: iconBase + "info-i_maps.png",
          },
        };
        const features = [
      
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
              43.3062762022,
              -2.7221442573
            ),
            type: "parking",
          },
          {
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
             43.279026635,
             -2.3127149418
            ),
            type: "parking",
          },
          
        ];

        // Create markers.
        for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
          const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: features[i].position,
            icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
            map: map,
          });
        }
      }
      
</script>
*/
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

Only create the map once.  Then add the polyline and the markers to that map.

[image]

**code snippet:**

```js
"use strict";

function initMap() {
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 9,
    center: {
      lat: 43.3473702427,
      lng: -1.7866905872
    },
    mapTypeId: "terrain"
  });
  const flightPlanCoordinates = [

    {
      lat: 43.3473702427,
      lng: -1.7866905872
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3473476954,
      lng: -1.7865623441
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3473729249,
      lng: -1.7862672172
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3474351186,
      lng: -1.7861244734
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3474754356,
      lng: -1.7859851662
    },
    {
      lat: 43.347496558,
      lng: -1.7858726811
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3475023415,
      lng: -1.7857427616
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3474533912,
      lng: -1.7856312823
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3467171248,
      lng: -1.7854733672
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3458278049,
      lng: -1.7851600517
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3450604416,
      lng: -1.7848521005
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3443607204,
      lng: -1.7850081716
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3441632427,
      lng: -1.7851468921
    },


    {
      lat: 43.3423870336,
      lng: -1.7862907704
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3423038851,
      lng: -1.7863221187
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3422126062,
      lng: -1.7863554787
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3421186451,
      lng: -1.7864152417
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3419943415,
      lng: -1.786458157
    },
    {
      lat: 43.341907924,
      lng: -1.7864865717
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3418141305,
      lng: -1.7864960432
    },

    {
      lat: 43.3395636734,
      lng: -1.7880662251
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3394773398,
      lng: -1.7880819831
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393750805,
      lng: -1.7881052848
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393117134,
      lng: -1.7881597672
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3392953686,
      lng: -1.7882843222
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3392989729,
      lng: -1.78845305
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393396251,
      lng: -1.788651282
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393413853,
      lng: -1.7887586541
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393360209,
      lng: -1.7888663616
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393474203,
      lng: -1.7890360951
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393621724,
      lng: -1.7891617399
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393969573,
      lng: -1.7892939225
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3394075185,
      lng: -1.7894147895
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3393995557,
      lng: -1.7894981895
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3400335629,
      lng: -1.7926760204
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3403750416,
      lng: -1.7943606991
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3404274285,
      lng: -1.794564547
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3405581024,
      lng: -1.7947906069
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3408577554,
      lng: -1.7962014489
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3409312647,
      lng: -1.7964569293
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3410289977,
      lng: -1.7968221288
    },
    {
      lat: 43.341086749,
      lng: -1.797145335
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3411341906,
      lng: -1.7975875642
    },
    {
      lat: 43.341227565,
      lng: -1.7978497501
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3414114639,
      lng: -1.7980664223
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3415769227,
      lng: -1.7981714476
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3416830376,
      lng: -1.7983020376
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3418867178,
      lng: -1.7984791473
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3423764724,
      lng: -1.7990746815
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3427510597,
      lng: -1.7992604245
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3428710885,
      lng: -1.7993480153
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3431115653,
      lng: -1.7995948624
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3436958678,
      lng: -1.8000118621
    },
    {
      lat: 43.34389125,
      lng: -1.800135579
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3441171423,
      lng: -1.8003076594
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3442825172,
      lng: -1.8004375789
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3444631472,
      lng: -1.8005764671
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3446667437,
      lng: -1.8007254135
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3448162768,
      lng: -1.8008333724
    },
    {
      lat: 43.3448740281,
      lng: -1.8008811492
    },

  ];
  const flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: flightPlanCoordinates,
    geodesic: true,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 1.0,
    strokeWeight: 2
  });
  flightPath.setMap(map);
  const iconBase =
    "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/";
  const icons = {
    parking: {
      icon: iconBase + "parking_lot_maps.png",
    },
    library: {
      icon: iconBase + "library_maps.png",
    },
    info: {
      icon: iconBase + "info-i_maps.png",
    },
  };
  const features = [
    {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(
        43.3062762022, -2.7221442573
      ),
      type: "parking",
    },
    {
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(
        43.279026635, -2.3127149418
      ),
      type: "parking",
    },

  ];

  // Create markers.
  for (let i = 0; i < features.length; i++) {
    const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: features[i].position,
      icon: icons[features[i].type].icon,
      map: map,
    });
  }
}
```

```css
/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#map {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="map"></div>
<!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap" async></script>
```

Comment: Great! thanks for that! I'll give it a try.